# Choppy Scrolling - Chrome

Tags: html, css, scroll, vertical-scrolling

I'm having problems with choppy scrolling on my website. It's based on the "Porto" theme. Based on their site: [DEMO](http://preview.oklerthemes.com/porto/4.0.0/index-header-navbar-extra-info.html), I can see that smooth scrolling is possible, but on my dev server: [HERE](http://www.rex.robosharp.com) (www.rex.robosharp.com). It's really choppy. It's frustrating me a lot, since I can't find the solution to it.

Comment: you should really ask that question to the people who make that template ..

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue on your dev server in chrome 44.0.2403.155 on Mac. I am however seeing laggy scrolling on the theme demo page. I think that has to do with how much animation is happening at once on that page, though.

Comment: @JesseDockett Another thing I'm experiencing is (without a better word to describe it) a "kickback". When I scroll past the navbar which should stick it scrolls back up a small amount. I can scroll normally after that. ON 44.0.2403.157 m (64-bit)

Comment: Are you saying that as you scroll it tucks up under the browser's toolbar and then drops back down quickly? If so, I see that, too. It's very minor, I've always taken care of it by having the point at which the menu changes from static to fixed be farther down the page and use a transition. That way the menu can tick while it is off screen and then come down like it is supposed to. Also adds a nice little bit of movement to the site to remind the user that there are inside pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to be an issue particular to my screen height / content height of the page. There seemed to be some strange behavior which caused the scrollbar to twitch. I added a few breaks and it stopped occurring. I also asked my friend to test it, and he didn't have that problem.

Comment: Did you friend not have the latest version of Chrome? Because the latest Chrome 49 has noticeable jumpy backgrounds since the smooth scrolling was enabled by default: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=599782